# Angular2 component template change on variable change

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I want a component that generates its template data completely out of a components variable.

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slot',
  template: '{{component}}',
  styleUrls: ['./slot.component.css']
})
export class SlotComponent  {
  private component:string;
  constructor(
    public dataService : DataService
  ) {
    this.component = '<app-menu id="1"></app-menu>';
  }

}
```

Other components should be rendered if the variable changes. What I get is '`<app-menu id="1"></app-menu>`' as a string if I try it this way. But I want the component be rendered as it will done this way:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slot',
  template: '<app-menu id="1"></app-menu>',
  styleUrls: ['./slot.component.css']
})
export class SlotComponent  {
  private component:string;
  constructor(
    public dataService : DataService
  ) {

  }

}
```

Is there a way to adwise angular to parse the variable as HTML? Or an other way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: well {{}} is string interpolation thus it is not going to work like that. You would have to instantiate component by yourself and inject generated HTML markup. IDK how to do it, but somebody will for sure. Anyway, I think you are trying to do things WRONG WAY.

Comment: I would love to see a way to do it the RIGHT WAY!.

Comment: But I don't know what you want to do - your own router outlet? Cuz this looks like that.

Comment: I want to load Data from a Server and put components in Template slots as stored in the database. There are multiple slots in Template and what should be Renderd in the slots is stored in a db.

Answer (score 0):

Either you could put the components based on conditions using ngIfs / switchCases in your template or you could use dynamic component loaders to load components from ts file.

eg.

```
<app-menu1 *ngIf="component === 'app-menu1'"></app-menu1>
<app-menu2 *ngIf="component === 'app-menu2'"></app-menu2>
```

Comment: Yees, but than I have to edit this component every time another component hase to be possible. And mayby I want to render more then one component.